# Can a HKWorkoutBuilder object be used to collect workout data in an iPhone (with no paired Watch)?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

I am trying to figure out if I can use the HKWorkoutBuilder class on iPhone for workout data aggregation on the iPhone (for non-Watch users).

I watched the WWDC 2018 session number [707 New Ways to Work with Workouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/707/), which introduces the new workout APIs. They demo it with the Watch, but make no mention of whether it can be used on the iPhone as well. [HKWorkoutBuilder's documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutbuilder) on developer.apple.com mentions it being supported in both iOS and watchOS, as does the function [beginCollection(withStart:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutbuilder/2962913-begincollection).

I have looked on the Net but can't find any tutorials or even any mention of it working on the iPhone alone. Or does it work on iOS as well, only so that Bluetooth-connected devices like Fitbit can provide the data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. HKWorkoutBuilder's documentation page shows it is available on iOS 12+ and watch 5+

HKWorkout data is supported by [HKSampleQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksamplequery) which is used to query HealthKit data. So you should be able to get workout data on iOS without Watch.

Make sure data exits from other sources like apps/device and you have right permissions.

Comment: So I will have to collect data manually from CMPedometer and CLLocationManager instances and this would just help me in saving granular data to HealthKit? Also does HKQuery respond timely with HKSampleQuery to be able to display live workout stats like distance and pace?

Comment: You don't have to write data to read it. Apple Health is shared store for all sources. So you can read data from other sources and your data can be read by others.

Comment: I am trying to build a workout app. That's the main reason I am looking into this API. I was hoping to have an easier time calculating time (total, elapsed, etc. considering pauses/resumes), distance covered and pace. Will this give me direct updates for distance/pace?

Comment: I have not checked if what you looking for is supported by HealthKit. If it is, yes you can read and get update callback everytime that data is changed.